how to launch gnome-shell --wayland via remote ssh terminal?
I am struggling to launch the gnome-shell --wayland from the remote ssh terminal.
Currently, If I want to launch it then I have to launch it from the terminal which is shown on my displays connected to system.
But with the same command, it doesn't launch from the ssh terminal.
This is required for me for automation.

Usually, to activate GUI, you do systemctl isolate graphical.target. To make it default for boot, use systemctl set-default graphical.target. PS to switch back to "text mode", you use systemctl isolate multi-userl.target
